# Classify legal content in health services

Tags: information-architecture, content-strategy, classification

The health service of a county have content scattered across different environments in different software versions. Users are confused of which application to use for what content and try their best based on advice from colleagues and access rights. This has led to a situation where content is stored on places it shouldn't be. At worst sensitive content is stored in places where everyone with domain access have read permission. Thankfully the implementation of search is poorly done which means that content are hidden in a "I can't see the forest since all the trees are in the way"-fashion.

There is a need to create a thorough plan that address legal concerns. Especially data on patients need to be identified, classified and moved to a new storage location. Legal have several aspects such as

- Person identification (Social security number)
- Patient records
- Malpractice reporting obligation
- Anonymous records in research projects
- Authorization management
- Information retrieval records
- ...

It's a quite difficult environment to classify content only using the basic two-dimensional spread sheet. Here we have four or five facets of the content that are to be classified, and there is a need to get a clear picture of what goes where and why. How do I classify multiple facets of content in a presentable form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two different stages in your case.

### 1. Building Classes

> We have four or five facets of the content that are to be classified

Class, as a set of objects, can be created with filtering. So you need no any complex multidimentional visualization, instead use a list view.  See how ebay manages multi-faceted items:
[image]

Additionally you need an UI for labeling created classes, and a mean for storing the rules for each class.
.

### 2. Presenting Results

> There is a need to get a clear picture of what goes where and why

The result are the set of classes, filled with content items. So it's clear What goes Where. To answer Why question, you need to supply the filtering rules for each class, so the whole picture becomes obvious for users. List view for each class will work good. 
.

### ...

The benefits of the approach:

- Separate the processes of creating and using the classes (assuming
  the creation process involves the subject experts)
- Creating own classes, which are more understandable for end users (classes hide the complexity/busines rules from end users)
- Rules allow to automate the process of classifying for the future content